# NServiceBus, sharded master-data

Tags: soa, nservicebus

Say Service1 manages A-Z of some object-type. Client1 and client2 could then Send query- and update-commands to Service1. If Service1 Publishes events then clients could Subscribe.

How should this be handled if Service1 is sharded so that Service1a has A-M and Service1b has N-Z?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. A request goes to the source? I thought things come from a source and go to a target/destination. Is this right, sometimes ErpId isn't known and the message has to be sent to all ERP systems? Or, is the client the actual place where all processing takes place?

Comment: Yes, the first. Multiple erps do the same business-steps and should be presented as one to clients. Had there been only one erp-system I would send-reply for data, and the erp-system could publish. Here it is not possible since data is spread. There is not a 1:1 relationship between message-type and erp-endpoint.

Comment: You need to give more details. Are you trying to only integrate the existing ERPs (ie changes can only be done outside of the ERP systems and there will never be any intention to modify the ERP systems)? Is there one ERP system per department (where each department has a copy of the same system with different data)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question as best I could. I now discovered the overload `Bus.Send(string destination, params IMessage[] msgs);`. I'll see if it is suitable for 1 and 2.

Comment: Will there be services per ERPS that subscribes to a particular message type? And will you have a service publishing the message type and every subscriber will receive the message and return back to result to the originator?

Comment: Yes, and not sure. I've added a rephrased version of the question without mention of erp.

Comment: Question overhauled after [consulting meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168017/157627)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and you want one common interface to the clients, then one endpoint should be exposed to the client and that endpoint should be responsible for handling how and where to store the data.  It sounds like this may be some kind of content based routing.

The events would be published from either service as long as they do not overlap.  This implies there is one and only one logical Publisher.  Clients would subscribe to all events and just drop the events that they don't care about.

Comment: Hm, that one endpoint would be a single point of failure. Can the routing be moved to the individual clients instead? How can the two physical publishers be combined into one logical?

Comment: You could put the 2 Publishers behind a Distributor.  In this case the Publishers would not shard the data, but simply distribute it instead.  Another idea is that the common endpoint could also be a load balanced HTTP endpoint that handles the routing to give you better availability.